# Does QGIS 3.6.0 make use of GPUs in order to accomplish 2D tasks (rendering, zooming, panning...)?

Tags: qgis, hardware-recommendations, hardware, gpgpu

does anyone know whether last versions of QGIS (like last one, 3.6.0) make use of GPUs (either integrated or dedicated ones) in order to accomplish 2D tasks (rendering, zooming, panning...)? If it does, is GPU memory amount important for those tasks?

Answer (score 4):

For now I'm testing Nvidia Quadro 5000 with OpenCL and Qgis 3.6.x.
You can enable this in Settings -> Options -> Acceleration. For now it seems to be stable however note warning below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to Docs, which You can find on [Qgis Docs Page](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#rendering-settings) you can set setting relevant to CPU rendering. Docs don't mention GPU involved in rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have any citations for you, I can assure you that while acceleration might be used, the GPU has zero influence on QGIS' rendering speed. The vast majority of time spent rendering comes from getting the data from the data source and in some cases from non-ideal sequential rendering (e.g. on Draw Effects).

Do not buy some GPU or base a decision about hardware on a GPU if you think it has *any* impact on QGIS performance.

There might be *some* *few* algorithms using GPU in the future but that is still not something where even thinking about it would be reasonable.

tl;dr: Acceleration might be used but due to the nature of QGIS' design, it has a negligible impact on actual UX. Data access represents the vast majority of time spent between user interaction and the updated canvas.